# How to add links to pages dynamically in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

My pages controller has this code:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @pages = Page.all
  end

  def new
    @page = Page.new
  end

  def edit
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @page = Page.new(page_params)
    @page.save
    redirect_to @page
  end

  def update
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
    @page.update(page_params)
    redirect_to @page
  end

  def show
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
    @page.destroy
    redirect_to pages_path
  end


  private
  def page_params
    params.require(:page).permit(:title,:description)
  end

end
```

And in my navbar I have this code:

```
<% @pages.each do |page| %>
        <li?<%= link_to 'page.title', page_path(page)%></li>
    <% end %>
```

The code should generate the titles of each page created, however I get the following error when I run the page:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

I thought I had eliminated this issue by entering the code inside the new function in PagesController. This pages controller is just for additional pages. The navbar also contains links to static pages, so there should always be some value in the navbar.

Has anybody any advice?

Comment: Does it work for `index`, but not `show`. Or, does it never work?

Comment: It works other than in the nav bar. I have a separate page where the user can create read update and destroy pages. This functionality works there but not in navbar

Comment: What controller/action is being called when the nav bar throws the error?

Comment: <% @pages.each do |page| %> is giving the error. The method each is not defined when there are no pages added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Add this in your **application_controller.rb**

```
@pages = Page.all
```

and in your **navbar**

```
<% @pages.each do |page| %>
  <li><%= link_to "#{page.title}", page_path(page)%></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you! This woks. I had not added @pages = Page.all to the application_controller.rb Thank you so much

Comment: Doing it this way means that every web request will load all pages into memory. The proper way would be to set `@pages` as before_filter (before_action in Rails 5) in the controllers that need `@pages` populated.

Comment: @scarver2 Yes, but he needs to have it there because he wants all pages to be available to the main navbar which appears in every view. I don't know why he needs that, but yeah, it's not good to load all pages into memory for each request.

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like you don't have any pages in your `Page` table. Ensure you have populated this table with some pages.

You can also wrap the code in an `unless` clause to check if `@pages` is nil.

For example:

```
<% unless @pages.nil? %>
    <% @pages.each do |page| %>
       <li?<%= link_to 'page.title', page_path(page)%></li>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```